# I asked a bad question, how should I fix that?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

The question I am talking about is [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174453/when-you-cast-flock-of-familiars-is-your-regular-familiars-telepathy-improved) about the telepathic range of a familiar previously summoned by Find Familiar while a Flock of Familiars spell is active by the same caster.

Now, the people or RPG.SE seemed to have found this question reasonably good - worty of upvotes - but I disagree, the question creates unclarity by asking two seperate questions within the question body, one of which is not even mentioned in the title.

It asks (1) does the telepathic range of your Find Familiar increase to match that of the Flock of Familiars and (2) does using the senses of your Flock of Familiar cause you to be blind/deaf to your own senses.

Question 1 is the one I asked in the title and has remained unanswered. Question 2 was considered only in the body of the question and has been given a proper answer.

I can see a few possible ways to deal with this:

1. Set a bounty;
2. Change the question body to match question 1 and ask question 2 seperately;
3. Change the question body and title to match question 2 and ask question 1 again;
4. Delete the original question and ask both question 1 and 2 a second time.

Option 3 seems best to me although I would be changing my question to match the answer, would this be frowned upon or applauded?

What course of action do the people RPG.SE consider best in this situation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Option #3: Edit the current question to only ask about #2 and ask #1 as a new question

Your two questions seem pretty independent of each other. Since you already have an answer to one of them and the other wasn't addressed at all (I can see why, IMO it wasn't super clear that it was intended to be a question by my reading). If it had been clear, I think people would have advised the questions been separated from the get-go I think (I certainly would have).

So my advice would be to edit the current question to just be asking about the second question ("does using the senses of your Flock of Familiar cause you to be blind/deaf to your own senses?") then ask the first question ("does the telepathic range of your Find Familiar increase to match that of the Flock of Familiars?") as a new one.